# form.reset in javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

The button is for controlling the display of the form. My goal is that when the user clicks the button to remove the form:

1. the form will be removed from the screen
2. the button value becomes "add"
3. the form will be reset, so the user can't submit the form.

I was able to get number 1 and 2 to work. However, I was not able to reset the form (i.e. the value input still has value, and the user can still submit the form)

```js
function formHandler() {

  var displayStatus = document.getElementById('form1').style.display

  if (displayStatus === 'none') {
    document.getElementById('form1').style.display = '';
    document.getElementById('geoButton').value = "Remove";
    document.getElementById('form1').reset();
  } else {
    document.getElementById('form1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('geoButton').value = "Add";
    document.getElementById('form1').reset();
  }

}
```

```html
<div id="form1">
  <div class=".col1" style="float:left;vertical-align: middle;">

    {{ form.region }} {{ form.operator }}
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-2 style=" vertical-align: middle; ">
   {{ form.value }}
  </div>
   
  </div> 
   <div>
    <input id = "geoButton " type="button " class = "btn " value="Add " onclick = "formHandler() " />
   </div>
```

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: change `div id="form1"` to `form id="form1"` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @JayGould that will most definitely make a difference, good catch.

Comment: yea, change `div` to `form`. Also, you can add a `type=reset` button instead of calling a function. FYI: Reset button might not reset to blank because I could recall that it will reset to what form controls had values at page load.

Comment: @JayGould Thank you! It worked!

Comment: @iMatoria thanks!It's working now.

Comment: @Script47 Thank you!

Comment: `<div id="form1">` isn't a form...

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```js
function formHandler() {

  var displayStatus = document.getElementById('form1').style.display

  if (displayStatus === 'none') {
    document.getElementById('form1').style.display = '';
    document.getElementById('geoButton').value = "Remove";
    document.getElementById('form1').reset();
  } else {
    document.getElementById('form1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('geoButton').value = "Add";
    document.getElementById('form1').reset();
  }

}
```

```html
<form id="form1">
  <div class=".col1" style="float:left;vertical-align:  middle;">
    {{ form.region }} {{ form.operator }}
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-2" style="vertical-align: middle;">
    {{ form.value }}
  </div>

</form>

<div>
  <input id="geoButton" type="button" class="btn" value="Add" onclick="formHandler()" />
</div>
```

Calling reset on form1 wont do anything in your code because it's a div and not a form. Calling the reset function on a div results in a console error that basically tells you that function is not available.